# Get the total days from datepicker

Tags: javascript, python, django, function, datepicker

I'm using Django to build an app simulating a car rental. I have been trying to get the starDate - endDate to get the totalDays and multiple by the car.price to get the car.total

When I have the the total, then I can submit the form to book the rental

Here's a little bit of what I have for now:

```
<p id="price">${{ car.price }} per/day</p>
<p id="total">>Total ${{ car.total=car.price*totaldays }}</p> //car.total=car.price*totaldays here is to visualize what I need

<div>
  <form action="{% url 'add_booking' car.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ booking_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add booking">
  <table class="striped">
</div>
    
<script>
  var start_dateEl = document.getElementById('id_start_date');
  var firstDate = M.Datepicker.init(start_dateEl, {
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date(),
    yearRange: 1,
    setDefaultDate: true,
    autoClose: true,
    onSelect: getStartDate => {
      startDate = firstDate.date
      console.log(startDate)
      return startDate
    },
  });
  var end_dateEl = document.getElementById('id_end_date');
  var today = new Date();
  var tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var topMaxDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 90);
  var lastDate = M.Datepicker.init(end_dateEl, {
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: tomorrow,
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(topMaxDate),
    setDefaultDate: true,
    autoClose: true,
    onSelect: getEndDate => {
      endDate = lastDate.date
      console.log(endDate)
    },
  });

  const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
  const startDate = firstDate.date;
  const endDate = lastDate.date;
  const totalDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below get the difference between two date in days. You need to use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.round`. If car is rented and returned back on the same day. `Math.round` will result 0 days where as `Math.ceil` will result 1 day.

```js
console.log(Math.round(0.49)); // This will result 0
console.log(Math.ceil(0.49)); // This will result 1
```

```js
const MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const dateDiff = (date1, date2) => {
  const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
  const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / MS_PER_DAY); 
  return diffDays;
}

const d1 = new Date('5/13/2020');
const d2 = new Date('5/15/2020');
console.log(dateDiff(d1, d2));
```